# Can I periodically run a background task in WP8 without my app running?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, windows-phone-8, background-process, azure-mobile-services

I want to potentially update the tile of my WP8 app periodically - no more frequently than every hour or two. However, I don't want my app to have to be running for this background task to take place (will query a WAMS and, based on the returned results, update the WP8 app's tile).

Is this possible, or do background tasks (I found this tutorial on how to create one: 
http://thesociablegeek.com/windows-8/livetiles/modifying-live-tiles-in-a-background-process/) require that the app that hosts them be running?

IOW, what I basically need is similar to a Windows Service, that his hosted by the OS, not a/my particular app.

Comment: Is Scheduled Task not available on WP8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a guide how to use so called Background Agents in Windows Phone 7 or 8:
[Background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
Basically you can schedule simple task to be executed every 30 minutes, even the main application is not running. There are system requirements on these tasks like memory cap constraint 6 MB for WP7 and 11 MB for WP8 tasks, run time of each task 25 seconds, and limited available APIs.

Comment: What about deployment to the Windows Phone store - can you bundle these separate-but-joined-at-the-hip (Siamese twin?) apps together - the "main" app and the background task? If so, how? If not, how can you make sure the user also downloads the background task (surely a background task "app"/service is not deployed standalone to the WP8 Store).

Comment: Background task is a part of the actual app package, it's not twin or second app. It's all downloaded in one package.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you code your tile update logic as a [periodic task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)   and then configure  it to run in background. this way, you don't have to maintain your app running in background.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks promising, but it says, "Scheduled Tasks and background agents allow an application to execute code in the background, even when the application is not running in the foreground" Does this mean the app has had to be started by the user during the current session (since the phone has been turned on)? IOW, does the app have to be suspended for this to work, or will these periodic tasks even run if the user has not started my app, or it has been tombstoned/86d? And, just as important in my situation, as there are limitations for these tasks: can they access WAMS - querying a DB there?

Comment: Clay, what Dhawalk mentioned is the correct approach, and to answer your questions: A period task is created as a separate project from your WP8 app, as such the running of the task's logic is practically separated from the main app. WAMS can be accessed from the periodic task, not a problem. Alas, one limitation for this approach is that once you declared the capabilities of periodic task, it will appear as a "background task" under your settings --> applications --> background tasks module. If a user turns of your app, the codes in your background agent will never run.

Comment: By "If a user turns of your app" do you mean "If a user uninstalls my app"? If so, that's fine - with the app uninstalled, the background task would be worse than worthless.